# Outer Firebase API is running twice

Tags: angular, angularfire2

When calling the function **changePassword()** the outer firebase API runs **twice**. The console shows same id list twice. How can I fix this error? **Inner firebase api causes this problem.** After removing the inner firebase API the problem is fixed.

```
changePassword(){
    this.userDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(y=>{
        const id = y.payload.doc.id;
        console.log(id)
        const data = y.payload.doc.data();
        if(this.userType=="admin" && data.adminId==this.adminId){ 
          if(data.password==this.prevPass){            
            this.afs.doc('userCredentials/'+id).update(this.password).then(_ => {
              this.openSnackBar("Password Changed","Done");
            });
          }
          else{
            this.waiting = false;
            this.openSnackBar("Incorrect Previous Password","Done");
          }
        }
      }))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a [mcve], for example what is `this.userDoc`? I suspect though that your update causes a change in `userDoc` collection, which fires the `snapshotChanges` again.

Comment: this.userDoc = this.afs.collection('userCredentials');

Comment: well then there is your answer, your `update` makes changes in `userDoc`, thus `snapshotChanges` is fired again.

Comment: Please can you tell me a fix for this? I 've tried a lot but I failed

Answer (score 2):

As we found out in comments that your `update` causes change in `this.userDoc`, it means that `snapshotChanges` is fired after the update. You can solve this with using `take(1)`, which only fetches it once.

```ts
this.userDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  take(1),
// ....
```

You could also consider restructuring your code a bit, convert the inner query to an observable and chain the requests with `switchMap` or `mergeMap` instead of nesting. But that is not related to this question.

Comment: **ERROR ReferenceError: take is not defined**

Comment: like this? `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'`?